# Redo for loop iteration in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, redo

Does Python have anything in the fashion of a "redo" statement that exists in some languages?

(The "redo" statement is a statement that (just like "break" or "continue") affects looping behaviour - it jumps at the beginning of innermost loop and starts executing it again.)

Comment: There are plenty of ways you can do this. For one, you could use a `while` loop and reset whatever your counter / condition is upon some evaluation.

Comment: Never heard of  such a thing. Sounds a lot like goto

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider: Perl uses it (for what that's worth). Think a `continue` that doesn't perform the loop advancement step. Since it's tied to the loop itself, it's not morally distinct from `continue` and `break` really; if you accept them as something other than just `goto`, then `redo` is no worse (or better).

Answer (score 10):

No, Python doesn't have direct support for `redo`. One option would something faintly terrible involving nested loops like:

```
for x in mylist:
    while True:
        ...
        if shouldredo:
            continue  # continue becomes equivalent to redo
        ...
        if shouldcontinue:
            break     # break now equivalent to continue on outer "real" loop
        ...
        break  # Terminate inner loop any time we don't redo
```

but this mean that `break`ing the outer loop is impossible within the "`redo`-able" block without resorting to exceptions, flag variables, or packaging the whole thing up as a function.

Alternatively, you use a straight `while` loop that replicates what `for` loops do for you, explicitly creating and advancing the iterator. It has its own issues (`continue` is effectively `redo` by default, you have to explicitly advance the iterator for a "real" `continue`), but they're not terrible (as long as you comment uses of `continue` to make it clear you intend `redo` vs. `continue`, to avoid confusing maintainers). To allow `redo` and the other loop operations, you'd do something like:

```
# Create guaranteed unique sentinel (can't use None since iterator might produce None)
sentinel = object()
iterobj = iter(mylist)  # Explicitly get iterator from iterable (for does this implicitly)
x = next(iterobj, sentinel)  # Get next object or sentinel
while x is not sentinel:     # Keep going until we exhaust iterator
    ...
    if shouldredo:
        continue
    ...
    if shouldcontinue:
        x = next(iterobj, sentinel)  # Explicitly advance loop for continue case
        continue
    ...
    if shouldbreak:
        break
    ...
    # Advance loop
    x = next(iterobj, sentinel)
```

The above could also be done with a `try`/`except StopIteration:` instead of two-arg `next` with a `sentinel`, but wrapping the whole loop with it risks other sources of `StopIteration` being caught, and doing it at a limited scope properly for both inner and outer `next` calls would be extremely ugly (much worse than the `sentinel` based approach).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. A redo would not be very pythonic, and emulating your for-loop with and flag to redo if necessary will be easy to follow for other people. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

No, it doesn't. I would suggest using a while loop and resetting your check variable to the initial value.

```
count = 0
reset = 0
while count < 9:
   print 'The count is:', count
   if not someResetCondition:
       count = count + 1
```

Comment: Using `reset` doesn't replicate what `redo` does in other languages. `redo` is `continue` without the loop increment/advance step, but it doesn't restart the loop from the beginning; you'd just make the `count` increment optional, not have a `reset` variable.

Comment: Ah, I misread your initial statement "it jumps at the beginning" to mean the initial point, not just the top of the loop. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I'm not the OP, it was their initial statement, not mine. I'll admit I could be misreading, but the only language I know of off-hand with `redo` is Perl, and it behaves this way. Note: The edited code is fine if you're replacing `for count in range(10):`, but it's not particularly generalizable to arbitrary iterables; my second code example in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36574072/364696) is the fully generalized version.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution using iterators:

```
class redo_iter(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.__iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.__started = False
        self.__redo = False
        self.__last = None
        self.__redone = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def redo(self):
        self.__redo = True
    @property
    def redone(self):
        return self.__redone
    def __next__(self):
        if not (self.__started and self.__redo):
            self.__started = True
            self.__redone = 0
            self.__last = next(self.__iterator)
        else:
            self.__redone += 1
        self.__redo = False
        return self.__last


# Display numbers 0-9.
# Display 0,3,6,9 doubled.
# After a series of equal numbers print --
iterator = redo_iter(range(10))
for i in iterator:
    print(i)
    if not iterator.redone and i % 3 == 0:
        iterator.redo()
        continue
    print('---')
```

- Needs explicit `continue`
- `redone` is an extra feature
- For Python2 use `def next(self)` instead of `def __next__(self)`
- requires `iterator` to be defined before the loop

Answer (score 1):

I just meet the same question when I study perl,and I find this page.

follow the book of perl:

```
my @words = qw(fred barney pebbles dino wilma betty);
my $error = 0;

my @words = qw(fred barney pebbles dino wilma betty);
my $error = 0;

foreach (@words){
    print "Type the word '$_':";
    chomp(my $try = <STDIN>);
    if ($try ne $_){
        print "Sorry - That's not right.\n\n";
        $error++;
        redo;
    }
}
```

and how to achieve it on Python ??
follow the code:

```
tape_list=['a','b','c','d','e']

def check_tape(origin_tape):
    errors=0
    while True:
        tape=raw_input("input %s:"%origin_tape)
        if tape == origin_tape:
            return errors
        else:
            print "your tape %s,you should tape %s"%(tape,origin_tape)
            errors += 1
            pass

all_error=0
for char in tape_list:
    all_error += check_tape(char)
print "you input wrong time is:%s"%all_error
```

Python has not the "redo" syntax,but we can make a 'while' loop in some function until get what we want when we iter the list.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sophiscated but easy to read, using a `while` and an increment at the end of the loop. So any `continue` in between will have the effect of a redo. Sample to redo every multiple of 3:

```
redo = True # To ends redo condition in this sample only
i = 0
while i<10:
   print(i, end='')
   if redo and i % 3 == 0:
      redo = False # To not loop indifinively in this sample
      continue # Redo
   redo = True
   i += 1
```

Result: 00123345667899

Answer (score 0):

There is no redo in python.
A very understandable solution is as follow:

```
for x in mylist:
    redo = True
    while redo:
        redo = False

        If should_redo:
            redo = True
```

It's clear enough to do not add comments

`Continue` will work as if it was in the for loop

But `break` is not useable, this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36574072/841871) make `break` useable but the code is less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for python 3.8+ since now we have [the `:=` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):

```
for key in mandatory_attributes:  # example with a dictionary
    while not (value := input(f"{key} (mandatory): ")):
        print("You must enter a value")

    mandatory_attributes[key] = value
```