# Is there a way to repeat a loop with same iteration?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, repeat

Is there a way to repeat a loop with same iterator without `i` incrementing by 1?

```
    for i in range(100):
        random_function()
        if status_code != 200:
            #repeat function with same iterator without incrementing by 1.
```

Comment: use a `while True` or `for _ in range(100):`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redo for loop iteration in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573486/redo-for-loop-iteration-in-python)

Comment: This gfg article can help you with that :- [increment Iterator from inside the For loop](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-to-increment-iterator-from-inside-the-for-loop-in-python/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a while loop and control the increment yourself

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    foo()
    if status == 200:
        i += 1
```

Or build the retry logic into your "random function"

Comment: Thanks, I can see the logic behind this, but what if the iteration was over a list rather than an integer?

Comment: Then use `while i < len(list)`