# What is the best way to repeat the current iteration of a loop without going to the next iteration?

Tags: python, loops, repeat

Sometimes inside a `for` loop I would like to be able to repeat the current iteration from the beginning, something like that:

```
for element in list:
    # top of for
    ...
    if condition:
        ...
        repeat # that would make the current iteration restart from the top
               # without getting the next element in the list
```

I usually emulate this behavior with a `while` inside a `for`:

```
for element in list:
    while True:
        # top of while=top of for 
        ...
        if condition:
            ...
            continue # repeat: go to the top of the while
        ...
        # last line inside the while will break the while 
        break
```

Is there a nicer way to do that?

Comment: I don't know of any language with a `repeat` statement like that.  It's a lot like a `goto` statement.  In my view, the nested `for`/`while` is the right solution.  The alternative is to make the outer loop a `while 1:` and then pull another item from the list when you need one.

Comment: "Best" is going to be subjective.  Personally I think a nested loop looks confusing, and if you're going to have a `while` loop anyway, I'd personally get rid of the outer `for`-loop and just use a `while` loop that explicitly advances an iterator or index for the `not condition` case.

Comment: On the topic of a `goto`, the official docs [have an explanation about why it is not implemented](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-is-there-no-goto). There is also an [answer here on SO about goto that can be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python) and provide more context.

Comment: The nested loop is *explicit*. The `for` loop is clear: the body is executed exactly *once* for each value assigned to `element`, so if the body needs to perform a repetitive operation, it needs to include a loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ruby has `redo` (got that name from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36573486/12671057), I guess this is a duplicate of that).

Answer (score 0):

If this is possible I would put the nested loop inside of a private function. that would be more clear. another option is to iterate the list

```
iter_list = iter(list)
value = next(iter_list,None)
while value is not None: # you reached the end of the iterator
    ....
    if not condition:
        value = next(iter_list,None)
        continue # condition isn't met skip to the next item
```